# Zxing library error on Vuzix glasses

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am facing a crash when calling the zebra crossing library,
the screen size of my glasses are 428/240,
here is my simple call

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);
    i.setAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    i.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "EAN_13,CODE_128");
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

and this is the error I'm getting,

```
01-01 02:28:13.726: E/CameraHal(127): (1d99b30)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:1185 setFormat - OMX_SetParameter - 80001001
01-01 02:28:13.726: E/CameraHal(127): (1d99b30)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:1246 setFormat - Exiting function setFormat because of eError = 0x80001001
01-01 02:28:13.726: E/CameraHal(127): (1d99b30)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXAlgo.cpp:1133 setSensorOrientation - Error while configuring format 0xffffffea
01-01 02:28:13.726: E/CameraHal(127): (1d99b30)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:2816 getFrameSize - Error configuring Sensor Orientation ffffffea
01-01 02:28:13.726: E/CameraHal(127): (1d99b30)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:1808 cameraPreviewInitialization - Error: CAMERA_QUERY_RESOLUTION_PREVIEW -22
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639): Unexpected error initializing camera
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager.startPreview(CameraManager.java:151)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivityHandler.<init>(CaptureActivityHandler.java:74)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.initCamera(CaptureActivity.java:688)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.surfaceCreated(CaptureActivity.java:386)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:536)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:82)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:170)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1617)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 02:28:13.734: W/CaptureActivity(2639):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have hardcoded the PreviewSize of the camera.
In the CameraConfigurationManager, change:

```
parameters.setPreviewSize(cameraResolution.x, cameraResolution.y);
//change into
parameters.setPreviewSize(1280, 720);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a driver or hardware error in the glasses, as the stack trace shows. It's not to do with the app. You can analyze the driver error and perhaps report it to the manufacturer. Also, try disabling the 'bug workaround' options in the app which are there to avoid common driver bugs.